# How do a conform to a protocol that declares property of type protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol and a couple of classes that conform to it. The protocol has an property which conforms to another protocol so the classes each need to have a property that matches.

This is (something like) what I'm trying so far:

```
protocol Edible {
    func eat()
}

class Apple:Edible {
    func eat() {
        print("Crunch")
    }
}

class Banana:Edible {
    func eat() {
        print("Homph")
    }
}

protocol Delicious {
    func consume()

    var fruit: Edible? { get set }
}    

class ToffeeApple: Delicious {
    func consume() {
        print("I like toffee apples!")
        fruit.eat()
        // ...
    }

    var fruit: Apple?
}

class BananaSplit: Delicious {
    func consume() {
        print("Ah! A banana split!")
        fruit.eat()
        // ....
    }

    var fruit: Banana?
}
```

The (relevant) error I'm getting is "Type 'ToffeeApple' does not conform to protocol 'Delicious'" (and the same for Banana and BananaSplit too). I thought the properties `Apple` and `Banana` would satisfy the requirements as they both conform to `Edible` as as `fruit` does. Am I declaring one of these incorrectly or is this not possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change from:

```
protocol Delicious {
    func consume()

    var fruit: Edible? { get set }
}
```

to:

```
protocol Delicious {
    func consume()

    associatedtype EdibleType: Edible
    var fruit: EdibleType? { get set }
}
```

`associatedtype EdibleType: Edible` means:

protocol `Delicious` has an unprovided type `EdibleType` which confirm to protocol `Edible`.

And the type should be provided when something is confirm to `Delicious`.

So in:

```
class ToffeeApple: Delicious {
    func consume() {
        print("I like toffee apples!")
        fruit.eat()
        // ...
    }

    typealias EdibleType = Apple
    var fruit: Apple?
}
```

The `EdibleType` is filled with Type `Apple`,

And in:

```
class BananaSplit: Delicious {
    func consume() {
        print("Ah! A banana split!")
        fruit.eat()
        // ....
    }

    typealias EdibleType = Banana
    var fruit: Banana?
}
```

The `EdibleType` is filled with Type `Banana`,

If you want learn more about this you can search around Swift Generics.

Comment: This works but I have no idea why! What does this change actually mean? I guess i need to read up on associatedtypes.

Comment: Answer updated. And this is what you want https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

protocol Edible {
    func eat()
}

class Apple: Edible {
    func eat() {
        print("Crunch")
    }
}

class Banana:Edible {
    func eat() {
        print("Homph")
    }
}

protocol Delicious {
    func consume()

    var fruit: Edible? { get set }
}

class ToffeeApple: Delicious {
    var fruit: Edible?

    func consume() {
        print("I like toffee apples!")
        fruit?.eat()
    }

}

class BananaSplit: Delicious {
    var fruit: Edible?

    func consume() {
        print("Ah! A banana split!")
        fruit?.eat()
    }
}

let bananaSplit = BananaSplit()
bananaSplit.consume() // Ah! A banana split!
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised I didn't see this. It does, however, mean that I can make a toffee apple with a banana instead of an apple, which wasn't exactly what I wanted. If I did want to enforce only making ToffeeApples out of Apple-ish fruits, would I just create a derived protocol of Edible (called Appley, for example)?